# PHP $_POST can't read values set by jQuery val()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I created a little script which allows users to shadow some input values from other inputs. The JavaScript part is working fine, but now when I'm trying to send the form, it doesn't send it, saying that the field the value is copied to is empty. What's the problem here? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(":text").blur(function() 
    {
        var input = $(this);
        var id = input.attr("id");
        var fieldname = "#".concat(id);

        for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        {
            if (fields[i][4] == id)
            {
                var boxname = "#copy_".concat(fields[i][0]);
                if ($(boxname).prop("checked"))
                {
                    var fieldname2 = "#".concat(fields[i][0]);
                    $(fieldname2).val($(fieldname).val());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $(":checkbox").change(function()
    {
        var input = $(this);
        var id = input.attr("id");
        id = id.substring(id.indexOf("_") + 1, id.length);
        var fieldname = "#".concat(id);

        var checked = input.prop("checked");
        $(fieldname).prop("disabled", checked);

        var field = FindField(0, fields[FindField(0, id)][4]);

        if (checked)
        {
            var fieldname2 = "#".concat(fields[field][0]);
            $(fieldname).val($(fieldname2).val());
        }
    });
});

function FindField(index, value)
{
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
    {
        if (fields[i][index] == value) return i;    
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The form (without some irrelevant stuff):

```
<form method="post" action="sendform.php">
    <table>

        <?php
            foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
                if ($field[0] == "divider") echo('<tr><td colspan="2"><hr /></td></tr>');
                else 
                {   
                    switch ($field[2])
                    {
                        case FIELD_TEXT:
                        {
                            echo('<tr><td><label for="' . $field[0] . '">' . $field[1] . ': </label></td><td>');

                            if ($field[4] != "") 
                            {
                                foreach ($fields as $field2)
                                {
                                    if ($field2[0] == $field[4])
                                    {
                                        echo('<input type="checkbox" id="copy_' . $field[0] . '" title="Kopeeri väljalt &quot;' . $field2[1] . '&quot;" />');
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            echo('<input type="text" id="' . $field[0] . '" name="' . $field[0] . '" placeholder="' . $field[1] . '" /></td></tr>');

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>

        <tr><td colspan="2"><hr /></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="submit" value="Saada avaldus" name="saadaavaldus" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

A sample of the fields array:

```
var fields = <?php echo json_encode($fields); ?>

$fields = array
(
    //      ID/name         label/placeholder                       type            regex                                                          field copied from
    array(  "saatjanimi",   "Teie täisnimi",                        FIELD_TEXT,     "^[-,.'\s\pL]*\pL[-,.'\s\pL]\s+[-,.'\s\pL]*\pL[-,.'\s\pL]*$",   ""),
    array(  "meiliaadress", "Teie meiliaadress",                    FIELD_TEXT,     "^([\pL-.\d]+)@([\pL-.\d]+)((\.(\pL){2,63})+)$",                ""),
    array(  "isanimi",      "Lapse isa täisnimi",                   FIELD_TEXT,     "^[-,.'\s\pL]*\pL[-,.'\s\pL]\s+[-,.'\s\pL]*\pL[-,.'\s\pL]*$",   "saatjanimi")
);
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the form? Do all the fields have a `name` attribute?

Comment: How is the data being sent from jQuery to PHP? The only real way to send info from JavaScript to PHP (without using a framework like Angular) is through AJAX. PHP should receive the information from the form and not from the jQuery unless you use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Baruch It's sent by a regular HTML form, added it to the OP.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Do you mean where it's sent or where it's received? Anyway, added the form.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Added the form.

Comment: Read the 2nd part of his comment

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I'm confused now. Do you mean that I should override how the form is submitted so it's posted with $.ajax()?

Comment: No. You need to add a name attribute to your copy inputs otherwise the browser won't submit them.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ The checkboxes don't need to be submitted, they are there just for ticking to specify if the value of the text input next to it should be copied.

Comment: Ah ok. Please can you show the rest of your JavaScript. What is var fields?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Added a sample of the array. I feel like the mistake isn't there, I found another question similar to this, but it wasn't very helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004154/php-post-is-empty-after-using-jquery-val-on-input